# How to wrap a multithreaded callback for async/await?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, synchronizationcontext

I have async/await code and want to use an API similar to a websocket. It takes a callback for receiving new messages which is called from another thread.

Can I execute this callback in the same async/await context as the connection initiation without resorting to locking?

I think this is what SynchronizationContext is for but I can't tell if its threadsafe. If I log the thread-id, each callback will be on a different thread. If I log Task.CurrentId its null. I think the same synchronisation context moves across different threads so this might be ok but I don't know how to confirm it.

```cs
// External api, the callbacks will be from multiple threads
public class Api
{
    public static Connect(
        Action<Connection> onConnect,
        Action<Connection> onMessage) 
    {}
}

async Task<Connection> ConnectAsync(Action<Message> callback)
{
    if (SynchronizationContext.Current == null)
    {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());
    }

    var syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Connection>();

    // use post() to ensure callbacks from other threads are executed thread-safely

    Action<Connection> onConnect = conn => 
    {
        syncContext.Post(o => tcs.SetResult(conn), null);
    };
    Action<Message> onMsg = msg => 
    { 
        syncContext.Post(o => callback(msg), null);
    };

    // call the multi-threaded non async/await api supplying the callbacks

    Api.Connect(onConnect, onMsg);

    return await tcs.Task;
}

var connection = await ConnectAsync(
    msg => 
    { 
        /* is code here threadsafe with the send without extra locking? */ 
    });

await connection.Send("Hello world);
```

Comment: I didn't understand what are you trying to do, but can say that Posting to `SynchronizationContext` (to this specific one you use in your code, if `SynchronizationContext.Current` is null) will just execute callback on thread pool thread, that's all.

Comment: Could multiple calls to Post() on the same context be executed in parallel or are they guaranteed to be in series even though they are not on the same thread?

Comment: On this specific context (basic `SynchronizationContext` you set with `SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext())`) - posting just dispatches callback to thread pool thread and that's all, nothing else is done. So yes - callbacks will be executed in parallel. On other contexts that might be different.

Comment: I see. So that means UI threads are encapsulating a thread and implementing a message pump as their SynchronisationContext but this one is not.

Comment: Yes that's correct. I'd say your library should not care about such things. Executing callbacks on background threads is common practice and caller should deal with that himself.

Comment: Thanks Evk, that got me to the solution. FYI the code was simulating a single-threaded execution model and I couldn't introduce normal multi-writer locking strategies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Evk who pointed out that the default SynchronizationContext doesn't actually synchronise anything or implement send/post in the way you would expect.

https://github.com/StephenClearyArchive/AsyncEx.Context

The fix is to use Stephen Cleary's async library which implements a SynchronizationContext as a message pump in a single thread so that the post() calls are called in the same thread as the other awaited calls.

```cs
// External api, the callbacks will be from multiple threads
public class Api
{
    public static Connect(
        Action<Connection> onConnect,
        Action<Connection> onMessage) 
    {}
}

async Task<Connection> ConnectAsync(Action<Message> callback)
{
    var syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Connection>();

    // use post() to ensure callbacks from other threads are executed thread-safely

    Action<Connection> onConnect = conn => 
    {
        syncContext.Post(o => tcs.SetResult(conn), null);
    };
    Action<Message> onMsg = msg => 
    { 
        syncContext.Post(o => callback(msg), null);
    };

    // call the multi-threaded non async/await api supplying the callbacks

    Api.Connect(onConnect, onMsg);

    return await tcs.Task;
}

//
// https://github.com/StephenClearyArchive/AsyncEx.Context
//
Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncContext.Run(async () =>
{
    var connection = await ConnectAsync(
        msg => 
        { 
            /* this will execute in same thread as ConnectAsync and Send */ 
        });

    await connection.Send("Hello world);

    ... more async/await code
});
```